# Cannot boot when I move /home and /usr to an lvm

Tags: boot, mount, root, fstab, lvm

I've got a pc with multiple drives and I wanted to make it seem like I only had one partition, so I wanted to use an lvm, but It's not a good idea to boot from an lvm, so I thought I could maybe make a small partition for booting and then mount folders like `/home` and `/usr` and others on the lvm using fstab (like other guides for moving folders to different drives suggest). I wanted to try it out first, so that I don't end up messing up my computer, so I used an old laptop with kubuntu 20.04. I set up an lvm using two usb sticks and copied the folders to it. Then I edited fstab to mount those folders in the root directory. I stil have copies of the folders in the root directory as well, because those guides say to delete them only after you reboot.

When I try to boot, though, it boots straight into the recovery shell or whatever it's called. If I exclude the entry for `/usr`in fstab, it does boot, but the screen is just black, except for the mouse pointer. I can move the mouse around, but that's it. No keyboard shortcuts work and not even the power-off button does anything.

Comment: I boot perfectly well from an LVM volume, and have done so for years, so you may have outdated information. That said, I dimly recall having your issue in the past, and the problem was that `grub` was missing its LVM module, since the original installation did not use LVM. I can't recall the process, hopefully someone else can, but you have to enable the LVM module in `grub` and `update-grub`, possibly also rebuild your `initramfs`.